# How can I create and add actions to jquery buttons using an object?

Tags: jquery, object, button

I have been successfully passing buttons to jquery ui dialogs by first defining an object.

I would like to replace the dialog for something very basic and more suitable for what I need.

The following illustrates what I am doing.

I label buttons and assign actions to each button as follows.

```
function defineButtons(){
var buttons={};
buttons['Reset']=function(){
    alert("Reset");
    alert("Something else");
}
buttons['Close']=function(){
    alert("Close");
    alert("Again");
}
return buttons;
```

}

I would like to now display these buttons as jquery ui buttons and, when each one is clicked, run the two respective alerts for each button.

I guess I could achieve this by looping through the object, which was defined above, as follows.

```
var buttons=defineButtons();
$.each(buttons,function(key,value){
    // What goes here?
});
```

Unfortunately I do not know what to put inside the loop.

If this is a valid question, would anyone be able to help?

Largely thanks to madalin ivascu's answer below the following appears to add actions and apply the jquery ui theme.

```js
$(function() {

var buttons = defineButtons();
$.each(buttons, function(key, value) {
  $('body').append('<div class="' + key + '">'+key+'</div>');
  var vclass = '.'+key;
  $('body').on('click',vclass,value);
  $(vclass).button();
});


function defineButtons(){
    var buttons={};
    buttons['Reset']=function(){
        alert("Reset");
        alert("Something else");
    }
    buttons['Close']=function(){
        alert("Close");
        alert("Again");
    }
    return buttons;
}

  });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
 $.each(buttons, function(key, value) {
  $('body').append('<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ' + key + '">A button element</button>');//append the elements on the page
  var vclass = '.'+key;
  $('body').on('click',vclass,value);//delegate the click event
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/tcbbcogd/

Comment: Looks like you've got the action sussed so this is great. However when I link in the jquery ui css I do not appear able to apply the jquery ui styling to the buttons. I think this may be possible by simply applying button() to each button. I am not sure how to do this right now.

Comment: as you can see in my jsfiddle the styles are applied using the corresponding ui classes

Comment: yes and that applied styles. However I think there may be a cleaner way of doing this which applies the linked-in theme. Perhaps along the lines of doing this: "$( ".selector" ).button();"

Comment: @wurzel_gummidge you can do that as well